# OutOfBlinkCors Flag not working in CefSharp Version 91

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

We recently upgraded CEFSharp version from v86 to V91. In v86, we used to get the error
net::ERR_FAILED  and this was due to cors preflight request was getting blocked resulting it into the above error. We get rid of this error in V86 by adding chromium flag
disable-features-OutOfBlinkCors and it fixed the issue.
Reffer this : https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/3006/outofblinkcors-m85-post-requests-fail-with

Recently when we upgraded to V91. Although we have the flag available, it is still giving the same error.

It seems OutOfBlinkCors is not supported anymore.

https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18157

Any help will be appreciated...

Also posted my question on CefForum
https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18597

Comment: As you've asked at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18597 please keep the discussion there.

Comment: @amaitland does chrome browser still supports legacy cors behavior? it works fine in chrome browser and edge browser latest version

Comment: It's possible the problem you are seeing is CEF specific, you'll need to follow up at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18597 your best bet is to provide an example as requested.

Comment: If you are using the default ResourceHandler implementation the  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set at   https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/92/CefSharp/ResourceHandler.cs#L112

Comment: That's the only CORS related header CefSharp currently uses.